# Code assist in Aptana Studio

Tags: jquery, aptana, code-completion

I'm a first time user trying to set up Aptana Studio 3 for HTML/CSS/JavaScript development. One thing that I'm having trouble with is getting code assist to work properly for jQuery.

When the code completion window pops up, it is filled with syntax that I don't even know how to read.

[image: Code assist]

Does this seem right to you? How do I fix it? What is this weird ${#:x} syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Installing the jQuery ruble does not automatically add it to your project. In order to do so:

Right click your project | Properties | Project Build Path | enable the appropriate version for your project, then rebuild.

[image]